# phantomjs 2.0 High memory usage on Linux

Tags: linux, phantomjs

For my project I use phantomjs 2.0 to generate charts images (Highcharts)

On windows when I generate images, phantomjs use 30Mo RAM (maximum 35 Mo)
On Linux (Debian 7.8), when I launch phantomjs, it takes 1.6Go RAM and when I generate image it takes 1.7Go maximum.

I don't undersand this big difference of memory usage.

Someone has any idea.

Comment: Considering that there isn't even an official linux release for v2.0.0, I have no idea how you got those numbers..

Comment: I download the source code phantomjs-2.0.0-source.zip on the official site http://phantomjs.org/download.html and I built it on debian

Comment: Please add more information so that the situation is reproducible for others.

Comment: I have the same problem with phantomjs 1.9

Comment: When I launch phantomjs.exe (without parameter) on my windows, it take 30 Mo when I generate an image. On linux when I launch phantomjs (without parameter), it take 1Go. My linux is a Debian 7.8.

Comment: Having the same problem. For me it shows 2GB of memory being consumed by phantomjs.

Comment: @isi - it's easily 'reproducible' - just use PhantomJs for any menial task on Linux and watch the footprint grow and grow.. This isn't a result of corner case usage. Can't for a moment believe that the PhantomJs team haven't seen this in their own development efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for 2.1.1, both the installed version from apt-get and from building it myself. Going back to 2.0.1 solved the issue for me.

Note that 2.0 has a few regressions - http://phantomjs.org/release-2.0.html